# SwiftUI ForEach does not compile with if block inside - Bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: if-statement, foreach, compiler-errors, swiftui

I am getting an error that I don't understand. I am not sure if it is a compiler error or if I am doing something wrong?

Inside a swiftUI View I have a list showing elements from core data (Figure 1). In the example below I replaced the t.name with "yo" for some undefined reason .

Anyway, the tasks is a fetch request from Core Data:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
```

FIGURE 1: Works fine to build and run the app.
[image]

FIGURE 2: Does not work to build and run the app.
[image]

**Please** help me understand what I am doing wrong or is this a compiler bug? Why can't I add the if block inside the ForEach? I can provide more information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Put the if block inside a `Group { ... }`. Does that work?

Comment: @ThomaVos It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return nil in case of a false condition. So you need to declare parameter as Optional and return nil in case of a false condition (XCode - 11.3.1).

```
ForEach(tasks, id: \.id) { t -> Text? in
    return condition ? Text("text") : nil
  }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI view builder does not require both `true/false` conditions handling, if one missed the EmptyView is injected automatically (otherwise our declarative view body would not look so pretty). Just be aware.

Comment: XCode 11.3.1 is showing me an error: "Missing return in a closure expected to return" when I'm trying to compile code without all conditions handling. Probably it could be avoided by some compiler preferences but I'm using settings from the box.

Comment: It is working normally with missed conditions in other constructions but not in ForEach.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `if` inside `ForEach`, but you should remember that `ForEach` is not language operator `foreach` but a struct type with ViewBuilder in constructor with generics in declaration, so it needs to determine type, which in your case it cannot determine.

The possible solution is to tell explicitly which type you return, as below (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
ForEach(tasks, id: \.id) { name -> Text in
    if (true) {
        return Text("name")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, in the `ForEach.init` you're using, the view building closure isn't annotated with `@ViewBuilder`. This means that the `if/else` you're using is Swift's own `if` statement, not the SwiftUI construct which returns a `_ConditionalContent`.

I don't know if it's considered a bug by Apple, but I would definitely consider it to be one.

The easiest workaround is just to wrap the `if/else` in a `Group` - the `Group.init` *is* a `@ViewBuilder`, so will handle the `if/else` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What also worked for me was using a `Group` inside the `ForEach` like this:

```
ForEach(self.items, id: \.self { item in
   Group {
       if item.id == 0 {
           Text(String(item.id))
       }
   }
}
```